# How to read data from a Vue instance

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Given the following code snippet:

```
 var title,description,lng,lat,identifier;
 const details = new Vue({
     el: '#detailsLOC',
     data: {
  resultsONE: [],
  resultsImages: [],
  GeoJsonONE: []
 },
 mounted() {
 axios.all([
     axios.get('/getJsonDetails'),
     axios.get('/getJsonDetailsImages'),
   ]).then(axios.spread((response1,response2) => {
    this.resultsONE = response1.data;
    this.resultsImages = response2.data;
    title = this.resultsONE.title;
    description = this.resultsONE.preview_description;
    lng = this.resultsONE.location_lng;
    lat = this.resultsONE.location_lat;
    identifier = this.resultsONE.identifier;
   })).catch( e => {
   console.log(e);
    document.getElementById("app1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app2").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("app3").style.display = "";
 });
 }
 });
```

I want to transfer/get/read the data from resultsONE and to save it outside the Vue instance(and store it in my example in these variable lng,lat,title,...).
Both axios.get are valid and are perfectly working.
Can you help me please?

Comment: details.$data will work I believe.

Comment: But data contains 3 objects,are you sure?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-data Inspect the contents of `details.$data`. It will contain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `data` object of a vue instance by referring to `instance.$data`.
A vue instace like this:

```
var foo = new Vue({
el: "#app",
data() {
  return {
    bar: "inside data"
  };
},
```

can be accessed via `foo.$data.bar`.

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4wwoxzow97